# como acceder al tono de llamada por actual con URI?

Tags: android, mediaplayer, uri

hola estoy haciendo una app de llamada falsa y no se como usar el tono de llamada por default que tenga el teléfono,estoy usando uri para guardar el audio que elija el usuario de su música solo me falta el de tono por defecto

```
prefs=getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        urimp3 = prefs.getString("urime",null);
        if(urimp3==null)
        {
            urim=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/mp3");
        }
        else{
            urim=Uri.parse(urimp3);
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("urime",urim.toString());
        editor.apply();
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), urim);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Comment: Me parece que en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271991/uri-to-default-sound-notification) tienes la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la `Uri` del sonido definido como predeterminado lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
Uri uriSoundDefault = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

Pero si deseas obtener la Uri para asignarla a una notificación no es necesario obtener la Uri, para esto se tiene la propiedad `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND` :

```
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

Comment: funciona SI el telefono tiene un rintong del sistema,yo tenia una cancion en mp3 para que suene cuando me llaman y al abrir la app no suena ,cambie a un tono de la lista del sistema y al abrir mi app si suena,sera que si el tono por defecto es una cancion que el usuario puso fuera de la losta del sistema reuqiero agregar un permiso o cambiar algo?